# Combine Netty and Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netty

How can I configure Netty in Spring MVC. When and where should I start the Netty tcp server? Should I init netty once the Spring starts? Could someone show me an example such as the Spring configuration xml file or something eles?
Thanks!

Comment: The better question not how, but does it make sense ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374277/combine-netty-and-spring-mvc

Answer (score 4):

It really depends what you are using Netty for. Assuming you are using it as an embedded HTTP server running on a separate port, you could simply initialise it within a Spring bean. I've achieved this in the past using a useful Netty/Atmosphere wrapper called [Nettosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/nettosphere):

```
@Service
public class NettyServer implements ServletContextAware {

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    private Nettosphere server;

    @Autowired
    private MyStatusHandler statusHandler;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialiseNettyServer() {
            String rootPath = servletContext.getContextPath() + "/api";

            server = new Nettosphere.Builder().config(
                    new Config.Builder()
                            .host(SERVER_HOST)
                            .port(SERVER_PORT)
                            .resource(rootPath + "/status", statusHandler)
                            .build())
                     .build();
            server.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdownNettyServer() {
            server.stop();
    }

}
```

This assumes the [annotation-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) in Spring, you can easily achieve the same result using XML as explained in [Jonathan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18375479/43662) answer.

Of course, you may prefer to use Netty directly, in which case the same principle applies, but you will need to dig into the [Netty user guide](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html) a bit to bootstrap the server correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a bean with `start` and `stop` methods that are responsible for starting up and shutting down the Netty server and then register the bean in the context with appropriate init and destroy hooks, e.g.:

```xml
<bean id="myNettyServer" class="x.y.z.MyNettyServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="shutdown"/>
```

Or alternatively use [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) and [`@PreDestroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html) annotations if you don't want to use XML configuration.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 (Just the code):**
Here's a really good example showing how to bootstrap Netty with a handler supporting Servlets (which in turn will delegate the job to Spring MVC) https://github.com/rstoyanchev/netty-spring-mvc

There you define *ServletNettyHandler* plus Java-based Spring MVC configurer (*DispatcherServletChannelInitializer*), and the *TestController* uses *@Controller* & *@RequestMapping* annotations as it always does in these cases.

Notes: Consider updating Netty & Spring version of the example to get it work.

**Option 2 (Just the blog post):**
I've found a blog post describing the process. http://www.hypersocket.com/content/?p=12

Comment: Both links are dead

Answer (score 0):

Actually with Spring 5 you can configure a [Spring 5 Webflux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html) application instead, it looks like a robust reactive alternative. The following lines (`Config.start()`) run a small HTTP server in parallel with the main execution with a Spring context.

```
@Configuration
public class Config extends DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration{
    @Bean
    String test(){
        return "Hello WOrLd";
    }

    @Bean
    AdminController controller(){
        return new AdminController();
    }

    public static void start() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        HttpHandler handler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(applicationContext).build();
        ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter = new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(handler);
        HttpServer.create("0.0.0.0", 8082).newHandler(adapter).subscribe();
    }
}
```

controller code:

```
@RestController
public class AdminController {
    @Autowired
    String text;

    @GetMapping(path = "/commands")
    Mono<String> commands(){
        return Mono.just(text);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
 compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.2.RELEASE'
 compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.2.RELEASE'
 compile 'org.springframework:spring-webflux:5.0.2.RELEASE'
 compile 'io.projectreactor.ipc:reactor-netty:0.7.2.RELEASE'
```

P.S. this example only uses Spring without Spring Boot which as good as a side embedded web server, but you should consider using Spring Boot for a full-fledged microservice development.