# Performance of Spring MVC with embedded Netty

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-mvc, netty

I know that Netty is very fast framework based on NIO. According to google researching there are a lot of good performance mark for widely range of protocols.

But I am really wondering about applying it to web app.
I found really interesting examples like :

[Combine Netty and Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374277/combine-netty-and-spring-mvc)

and really good example [here](http://hypersocket.com/content/?p=12).

It seems like makes sense to use it for web app, but I cannot find in google performance result for Spring MVC based on embeded Netty server.

I know that twitter and others world wide known projects use it, a lot of them only because of jdk 1.6 improvements, for own ByteBuffer implementation and so on, but I don't know about their usage netty for web app.

My questions:

1) Do someone know one of the good example of usage netty for HTTP protocol implementation.

2) Do someone consider performance for  this?

Comment: Spring and Netty are different beasts which offer a different set of features that may be useful in different situations.  Netty is going to allow you almost complete control and extensibility to control your own destiny and even to support protocols beyond HTTP.  Spring will likely get you started faster and has a lot of existing modules to help you (security, mvc, database abstractions, web flow, etc...).  Could you explain your use-case and what is your need to combine them?

Comment: yep, I am wondering of using netty as embedded server. for my web app. As I wrote in question there are some example of configuration it(it's not big deal to add security or other spring features there), so it's not a problem to use it, but I am more interesting about it performance and does it make sense.

Comment: Again too general.  Netty is general framework and tying it into Spring will rely upon your application code.  Assuming your problem does need both Netty and Spring your performance will more likely be tied to your application design in general rather than limited by Spring and/or Netty.

Comment: Ofc it relies to application code, but I am wondering does it make sense to use this combination. I am wondering maybe because programmers prefer tomcat or jetty, there is some reason for it.

Comment: You haven't described what you are trying to do in any detail so I'm not sure it is possible to answer your question. All of the implementations you have mentioned have their advantages and perform adequately for a large number of use cases.  As always your performance mileage will vary depending on your use case and if you are looking for actual numbers that will require you doing some experimentation.

Comment: Yeah, thanks ,seems like experimenting will be the easiest way to discover it.